# Unit testing, built in production dependencies

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0

Im reading The Art Of Unit Testing" and there is a specific paragraph im not sure about.

"One of the reasons you may want to avoid using a base class instead of an interface is that a base class from the production code may already have (and probably has) built-in production dependencies that you’ll have to know about and override. This makes implementing derived classes for testing harder than implementing an interface, which lets you know exactly what the underlying implementation is and gives you full control over it."

can someone please give me an example of a built-in production dependency?

Thanks

Comment: There is nothing bad to have a dependency in abstract class, unless you could inject the dependency with _fake_ implementation while testing. Usually this could be done using constructor, property or other kind of dependency injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My interpretation of this is basically anything where you have no control over the underlying implementation, but still rely on it. This could be in your own code or in third party libraries.

Something like:

```
class MyClass : BaseConfigurationProvider
{
}

abstract class BaseConfigurationProvider
{
    string connectionString;

    protected BaseConfigurationProvider()
    {
        connectionString = GetFromConfiguration();
    }
}
```

This has a dependency on where the connection string is returned from, perhaps a config file or perhaps a random text file - either way, difficult external state handling for a unit test on `MyClass`.

Whereas the same given an interface:

```
class MyClass : IBaseConfigurationProvider
{ 
    string connectionString;

    public MyClass(IBaseConfigurationProvider provider)
    {
        connectionString = provider.GetConnectionString();
    }
}

interface IBaseConfigurationProvider
{
    string GetConnectionString();
}
```

You are in full control of the implementation at least, and the use of an interface means that test versions of implementations can be used during unit tests, or you can inject dependencies into consuming classes (as I have done above). In this scenario, the dependency is on the need to resolve a connection string. The tests can provide a different or empty string.

Comment: Im still lacking knowledge in DI but the initial part of ur answer makes sense hence the upvote/marked answer. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: @HansRudel In a simple way, DI is just providing something else that gets what the class needs in the form of an interface, because interfaces can be implemented by anything underneath. What the class needs, in most cases, can be stated as "being a dependency" of that class, in my example, the class depends on a connection string for database access (the example is contrived, don't take this as a *typical* example).

Answer (score 0):

one example which i can think of is use of Session variable inside that of asp.net (im a .net guy)
because you have no control over how asp.net populates the session variable you cannot test it simply by making a test case you will have to either override it somehow or make a mock object
and this happens because all the context and cookies arent present when you are testing